# Default selected value on select are not visible when change value dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have 3 select dropdowns where 2nd and 3rd are depended on the choice of the 1st dropdown.

Each of them has a default choice to show when the page loads. I managed to make it work, so the 2nd and 3rd dropdowns will change options based on the first one, however, those two stays empty on load even if the first choice is selected when you click on them.

**HTML**

```
<div id="additional-number-options-284">
  <select class="form-control" id="select-additional-number-country-284">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a country</option>
    <option value="7818">Country 1</option>
    <option value="7814">Country 2</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-additional-number-state-284">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a state</option>
    <option data-product="7818" value="65">State 4</option>
    <option data-product="7818" value="66">State 5</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="62">State 1</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="63">State 2</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="64">State 3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-additional-number-plan-284">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a plan</option>
    <option data-product="7818" value="7819">Plan D (+$5.00)</option>
    <option data-product="7818" value="7820">Plan E (+$15.00)</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="7815">Plan A (+$10.00)</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="7816">Plan B (+$8.00)</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="7817">Plan C (+$12.00)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery("[id^=select-additional-number-country-]").change(function() {
  var id = this.id.split('-').pop();
  jQuery("#select-additional-number-state-" + id)
    .find("option")
    .show()
    .not("option:first, option[data-product='" + this.value + "']")
    .hide();

  jQuery("#select-additional-number-state-" + id).val(
    jQuery("#select-additional-number-state" + id).find("option:visible:first").val());

  jQuery("#select-additional-number-plan-" + id)
    .find("option")
    .show()
    .not("option:first, option[data-product='" + this.value + "']")
    .hide();

  jQuery("#select-additional-number-plan-" + id).val(
    jQuery("#select-additional-number-plan" + id).find("option:visible:first").val());

}).change();
```

[JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/yn4e56z0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because your attribute begins with selector is invalid. You need to wrap the value in quotes as the `-` will not be interpreted correctly. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('[id^="select-additional-number-country-"]').change(function() {
    var id = this.id.split('-').pop();
    $("#select-additional-number-state-" + id).val('').find("option").show().not("option:first, option[data-product='" + this.value + "']").hide();
    $("#select-additional-number-plan-" + id).val('').find("option").show().not("option:first, option[data-product='" + this.value + "']").hide();
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="additional-number-options-284">
  <select class="form-control" id="select-additional-number-country-284">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a country</option>
    <option value="7818">Country 1</option>
    <option value="7814">Country 2</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-additional-number-state-284">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Select a state</option>
    <option data-product="7818" value="65">State 4</option>
    <option data-product="7818" value="66">State 5</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="62">State 1</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="63">State 2</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="64">State 3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select-additional-number-plan-284">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Select a plan</option>
    <option data-product="7818" value="7819">Plan D (+$5.00)</option>
    <option data-product="7818" value="7820">Plan E (+$15.00)</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="7815">Plan A (+$10.00)</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="7816">Plan B (+$8.00)</option>
    <option data-product="7814" value="7817">Plan C (+$12.00)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Two other things to note here. Firstly the use of the aliased `$` parameter of the document.ready event handler. This allows you to use `$` instead of the verbose `jQuery` within the scope of the function.

Secondly your convoluted use of `val()` was not required. You can simply call `val('')` to reset the selected option when a dependant `select` is changed.

Comment: If you run the code snippet of your example, you can see that 2nd and 3rd select boxes are white as well. Without the first option visible on load.

Comment: That was because those `option` elements were missing the `value` attribute. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Wow.. Didn't know that this could affect the behavior. Thanks a lot.